# How to ask if the number is int or float for the user?

Tags: python, if-statement, integer, numbers

As I ask the user if the number is an integer, if he says yes, he will receive an int(input('text'))
otherwise, it will receive a float(input('text'))
?
ignore if i misspelled

Answer (score 0):

if you want the literal code you were asking for, than this is it:

```
if input("is the number an integar? ") == "yes": text = int(input("text"))
else: text = float(input("text"))
```

alternatively you can skip asking the user for the type and let your code figure it out:

```
text = input("text")
try: text = int(text)
except ValueError: text = float(text)
```

this for example trys to convert your text to an integar and if it doesent work it converts it to a float instead.